# I am comparing two consecutive cells within a column and if value matches then next sr no and if value doesn’t match then start from 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I want to create a formula in which column c is dependent on value of two consecutive cells in column B . E.g if cell B1 and cell B2 both are same then C2 = c1+1 and if they does not match then C2= 1. I want to make this formula in arrayformula so I don’t need to copy and paste in all cells. I used this formula if(B2<>B1,1,C1+1) in cell C2. Any help will be appreciated. If you have app script solution I don’t mind learning it.

Comment: May be by mistake, or doesn’t have any solution.

Comment: I have not downvoted this post. However, I understand why others are downvoting and voting to close. It lacks clarity. And that is largely because there is no sample data or expected outcome shown. The post also reports no research done. All of these elements are among the basic protocol for a post. I believe this does have a possible array-formula solution. Share in your post the research and new learning you've done as well as the attempts you've made, and you are more likely to receive the help you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

#### C = a[i - 1][0] == r[0] ? a[i - 1][0] + 1 : 1

```
function myfunk(col = 1, num = 1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  let vs = sh.getRange(sr, 2, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 1).getValues().map((r, i, a) => {
    if (i > 0) {

      return [a[i - 1][0] == r[0] ? a[i - 1][0] + 1 : 1];
    } else {
      return [''];
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(sr, 3, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```